# PostgreSQL: reuse Column Data In Different Column Of The Same Query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to create a `SELECT` query that does several calculated fields on one of two tables. I'm new to SQL (I've looked at several free online tutorials, so I have a general idea), but I think my goal is a little out of my skill range.

I have two tables:

- `TreeRecord` with columns `ID` (serial), `Site` (chr)

  Each ID represents an individual tree.
- `TreeHistory` with columns `ID` (serial), `TreeID` (int), `DBH` (int)

  DBH is tree diameter.

Currently I can create this:

```
 |  Site  |  Total tree count of site  |  Avg DBH of site  |
```

I would like to have another column that can give the total count of trees over a particular size for each site.  I can recreate this in a simple query, and my research on stack ([SQL Select - Calculated Column if Value Exists in another Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24021432/sql-select-calculated-column-if-value-exists-in-another-table)) makes me feel that a nested SELECT is what I'm after but I can't get that to work. My current code is this:

```
SELECT 
    "TreeRecord"."Site", 
    count("TreeRecord".*) AS Total_Count, 
    round(avg("TreeHistory"."DBH"), 0) AS Average_DBH
FROM 
    "TreeRecord"
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    "TreeHistory" ON "TreeRecord"."ID" = "TreeHistory"."TreeID"
GROUP BY 
    "Site"
ORDER BY 
    "Site" ASC;
```

Any help on this would be most appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure what your goal is, do you want to find all the trees of the site with WHICH size? the average?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `count` with the specific size condition.

```
SELECT "TreeRecord"."Site",
count("TreeRecord".*) AS Total_Count, 
round(avg("TreeHistory"."DBH"),0) AS Average_DBH,
count(case when "TreeHistory"."DBH" > 10 then 1 end) as count_over_specific_size          
                                      ^^--change this size accordingly
FROM "TreeRecord"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "TreeHistory"
ON "TreeRecord"."ID" = "TreeHistory"."TreeID"
GROUP BY "Site"
ORDER BY "Site" ASC;
```

Comment: wow i just finished my second university class about databases and never heard of that case statement, it is great!

Comment: @gbalduzzi Or `count("TreeRecord".*) filter (where "TreeHistory"."DBH" > 10)` for PostgreSQL 9.4 and above (as I remember).